# How to fix PlotLegends (position and font)?

Tags: plotting, legending

I have:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

p[n_, a_, b_] = E^(-a/n - b n)/Sum[E^(-a/n - b n), {n, 3, 12}];

exp[a_, b_] = Sum[n*p[n, a, b], {n, 3, 12}] // Simplify;

f[p6_?NumericQ] := NMinimize[{a^2 + b^2, exp[a, b] == 6, p[6, a, b] == p6}, {a, b}][[-1]]

funcs = Table[p[n, a, b] /.f[p6], {p6, {0.27, 0.25, 0.23, 0.21, 0.19, 0.17, 0.16}}];

DiscretePlot[Evaluate[funcs], {n, 3, 12}, Filling -> None,Joined -> True, 
PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{0.27, 0.25, 0.23, 0.21, 0.19, 0.17, 0.16}, 
LegendLabel -> Style[HoldForm[Subscript[p, 6]], FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"], 
LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}], {0.7, 0.65}], 
Ticks -> {{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, Automatic}, 
AxesLabel -> {Style[HoldForm[n], FontSize -> 20, 
FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"], Style[HoldForm[Subscript[p, n]], FontSize -> 20, 
FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"]}, 
BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"}, LabelStyle -> {18, GrayLevel[0]}]
```

which gives:

[image]

There are two problems:

1. How can I change the font of numbers in legends same as numbers in the axes, i.e., both to be romans?
2. Legends are interfering with the plots; however, if I move them further, they will go out. Is there a way to make the plot bigger so one can move the legends further?

**EDIT**

The second problem is solved in @cvgmt answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageSize -> Large` and set `TicksStyle`.

```
DiscretePlot[Evaluate[funcs], {n, 3, 12}, Filling -> None, 
 Joined -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{0.27, 0.25, 0.23, 0.21, 0.19, 0.17, 0.16}, 
    LegendLabel -> 
     Style[HoldForm[Subscript[p, 6]], FontSize -> 20, 
      FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"], 
    LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}], {0.7, 0.65}], 
 Ticks -> {{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, Automatic}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style[HoldForm[n], FontSize -> 20, 
    FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"], 
   Style[HoldForm[Subscript[p, n]], FontSize -> 20, 
    FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"]}, 
 TicksStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"}, 
 LabelStyle -> {18, GrayLevel[0]}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]